# Test Convergence of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}= \frac{(-1)^{k+1} k^{k} }{(k+1)^{k}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am trying to test the above series for convergence. First of all, it does not satisfy the conditions for the Alternating Test or the Dirichlet Test, since:  $\lim_{k \to \infty}a_{k} \to 1/e$.
I know that the series diverges, but I am not exactly sure how to prove it. I've considered other tests but they don't seem to be applicable.

Some of my classmates have said that $\lim_{k \to \infty}a_{k} \neq 0 \Rightarrow \sum a_{k}$ diverges. I don't necessarily agree with them, but I haven't really found a counterexample. Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Your classmates are correct. A fact commonly called the Divergence Test says that if $\lim_{k\to \infty} a_k \neq 0$ (i.e., the limit exists and is non-zero, or the limit fails to exist) then $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ diverges. (If you google Divergence Test, you can easily find a proof of this face).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your classmates are right. Suppose that $\sum a_n$ converges to $a$ and let $S_n$ be the sequence of partial sums. We have $S_n \to a$, hence $S_n - S_{n-1} \to a - a = 0$. But $S_n - S_{n-1} = a_n$. Hence $a_n \to 0$.

So if you proved that $\lim a_n$ does not exist or that it is non-zero, then you can conclude that the series diverges.

Now let $a_n$ be the general term of your series. We have $a_{2n -1} \to 1/e$ and $a_{2n} \to -1/e$. Hence $\lim a_n$ does not exist.

Comment: Well written.  +1.

Comment: Just for my own clarification, you showed it doesn't converge by supposing that it converges and examining subsequences, and since the limits of the subsequences give different values, the conclusion follows? I think that's what I was missing!

Comment: @FlashKicks909 yes, that's it.

Comment: @Dr.MV thank you. I appreciate that :)